# Difference between curated publications and additional publications in nextProt database?

Tags: bioinformatics, database

With reference to reference papers listed in nextProt database, what is the difference between curated publications and additional publications? Anyone using nextProt, kindly explain the terms. For example, when I search for SLC22A23 in nextProt simple search engine, I get as mentioned below on the left side toolbar.

References

Curated publications (21)

Additional publications (2)

Patents (0)

Submissions (0)

Web resources (0)

Link: https://search.nextprot.org/entry/NX_A1A5C7/

Thanks